# Struggling to put website online on CentOS 7 VPS with ISPConfig 3

Tags: dns, centos7, web-hosting

I added a website in ISPConfig attributed to no client because it's mine, using the nameservers provided by my hosting provider for my VPS, maybe a week ago, and trying to access it the IP address still cannot be found it says. How do I do this right, can someone just tell me please? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

1st create a normal account first then add your website on it. 
2nd you don't need to add any nameservers... just add the domain you wish and under your domain panel add an "A Record" pointing to your VPS. Report feedback once you do this please. A Records might take a while depending on DNS propagation (between 20 min and 72h)

Comment: So I've done that as of a few hours ago, pointing to my server, yes... and the nameservers they provided for mine. Will let you know once it's updated or it's been 72h.

Comment: Also I still have the DNS zone in ISPConfig, I should delete it right

Comment: DNS settings on ISPConfig are ignored if you do not change name servers under your domain panel. For example if your domain is from namecheap you will have ns1.namecheap.com and ns2.namecheap.com under your domain  panel. Just let the default nameservers and add an A Record pointing to your VPS IP. Sorry for the dealy I only check stack during work hours.